# No puedo reutilzar una funcion en laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

**estos son mis select que estan en la primer pantalla y si me funciona bien el problema es ala hora de hacerlos pero en otra pantalla me dejan de funcionar**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                             {!! Form::label('departa', 'Departamento:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                             <div class="col-lg-10">
                                 {!! Form::select('departamento',$departamento_honduras,null,['placeholder'=>'Selecciona','id'=>'departamento']) !!}
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <br>
                         <br>

                         <div class="form-group">
                             {!! Form::label('munic', 'Municipio:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                             <div class="col-lg-10">
                                 {!! Form::select('municipio',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],null,['id'=>'municipio']) !!}
                             </div>
                         </div>
```

**Estos son mis 2 select que quiero reutilizar en otra pantalla el problema es que no me esta funcionando no me tira nada solo me devuelve un json sin los datos que quiero**

```
 <div class="form-group">
         {!! Form::label('departa', 'Departamento:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
      <div class="col-lg-10">
         {!! Form::select('departamento',$departamento_honduras,null,['placeholder'=>'Selecciona','id'=>'departamento']) !!}
              </div>
              </div>
               <br>
               <br>

       <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('munic', 'Municipio:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
            <div class="col-lg-10">
        {!! Form::select('municipio',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],null,['id'=>'municipio']) !!}
               </div>
               </div>
              <br><br>
```

**esta es mi funcion que quiero reutilizar pero no me funciona con estos 2 select que tengo el problema es que con los select que tengo en la otra pantalla si**

```
$("#departamento").change(function (event) {
    $.get("municipios_dinamico/"+event.target.value+"",function (response,id_departamento) {

         console.log(response);
        // $("#unidades").empty();
        $("#municipio").empty();
        for (i=0;i<response.length;i++){
            $("#municipio").append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'>"+response[i].nombre+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

**esta es mi ruta que quiero reutizar igual**

```
Route::get('municipios_dinamico/{id}',[
    'as'=>'municipios_dinamico',
    'uses'=>'icf@municipio_dinamico_get'
]);
```

**esta es mi funcion del controlador la cual quiero reutilizar igual**

```
 public static function municipio_dinamico_get(Request $request,$id)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            $municipios=municipios::municipios_dinamico($id);
            return response()->json($municipios);
        }
    }
```

**y este es mi modelo el cual quiero reutilizar el cual devuelve los valores ala funcion de arriba**

```
public static  function municipios_dinamico($id){
        return municipios::where('id_departamento','=',$id)->get();
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? ¿El ajax, la función de laravel, el código de blade?

Comment: lo que no me funciona es el ajax  $("#departamento").change(function (event) {
    $.get("municipios_dinamico

Comment: al parecer si me captura el evento el problema es que no me quiere entrar en la ruta  y no se cual puede ser el problema

Comment: message 
exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
file D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php
line 179
trace […]
0 {…}
file D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php
line 636
function match
class Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection
type ->    esye es el jason que me trae y no los datos que quiero

Comment: <script src="{{ asset('/js/funcion.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script> de esta forma llamo mi funcion en public js en laravel

Comment: No me esta entrando ala ruta ese es el problema por que me tira un error 404 en la respuesta get al realizar un console.log(response)